# 3 sets of paired exclusion criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause, sql-like

I have a list of orders.

I have a 'holds' column in my table with concatenated hold codes.

I want to return all rows, including the rows that have a price of '0.01', UNLESS the rows with a price of '0.01' have one of 3 hold codes in the body of the OnHold column.

I attempted to approach it this way:

```
Select *

From Table

Where NOT (Price='0.01' AND onhold LIKE '%Pricing Hold%') 

AND NOT (Price='0.01' AND  onhold LIKE '%Program  Hold%') 

AND NOT (Price='0.01' AND  onhold LIKE '%Program Hold%')
```

This is excluding EVERYTHING with a Price of '0.01', including a row I have where Price='0.01' and onhold=Null. This leads me to believe that the grouping I am trying to do with the parentheses is not working.

How can I have 3 sets of paired criteria?

Update: so, to troubleshoot I updated the query just to say:

WHERE NOT (
onhold LIKE '%Pricing Hold%'
onhold LIKE '%Program  Hold%'
onhold LIKE '%Program Hold%'
)

And all that comes back is 1 record with an onhold value of ".New:Line Hold", but not the records that have Null onhold values. So now that has me thinking its how I am using "NOT LIKE '%%'", which is suppressing rows with blank "onhold".

Comment: Your updated query is not syntactically correct and will generate an error rather than returning any rows. But your query is very senstive to your data and that is why posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is highly recommended. You never mentioned NULL until your update - NULL is never equal to nor not equal to anything else. That is an important concept to learn when writing tsql.

Comment: Note @Smor he did mention NULLs in the original question: "*This is excluding EVERYTHING with a Price of '0.01', including a row I have where Price='0.01' and onhold=Null.*" Indeed, I believe the `onhold=NULL` is the only situation the OP's query *doesn't* work - it is the core problem in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you would like the only rows to be excluded are those where price = 0.01 and has a value in onhold being one of the three likes.

In the example data below, only the first row should be excluded in the result

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (price decimal(10,2), onhold varchar(30));
INSERT INTO #Test (price, onhold)
VALUES                   -- DESIRED RESULT
(0.01, 'Pricing Hold'),  -- Not included
(0.02, 'Pricing Hold'),  -- Included
(0.01, NULL),            -- Included
(0.01, 'No hold'),       -- Included
(0.02, NULL);            -- Included
```

In your code, the third line `0.01, NULL` is not included.

One approach is a tweak on your above to explicitly include/allow NULLS e.g.,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #Test
WHERE   Price <> 0.01 OR Price IS NULL
        OR onhold IS NULL
        OR NOT (
            onhold LIKE '%Pricing Hold%'
            OR onhold LIKE '%Program  Hold%'
            OR onhold LIKE '%Program Hold%'
            );
```

You could also use the EXCEPT clause - which is more readable but potentially less efficient

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #Test
  EXCEPT
SELECT  *
FROM    #Test
WHERE   Price = 0.01
        AND (onhold LIKE '%Pricing Hold%'
            OR onhold LIKE '%Program  Hold%'
            OR onhold LIKE '%Program Hold%'
        );
```

Both of the above return the following

```
price   onhold
0.01    NULL
0.01    No hold
0.02    NULL
0.02    Pricing Hold
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=399cd515feb3f3cd03a62f66b7688461) with my results. It is worth checking other answers how they deal with NULL values.

Comment: You seem really invested in getting the solution mark, and youre technically right that you were onto NULL being the root of the issue, even if you did offer an answer that was more roundabout than something I could actually implement.

Comment: Thanks - but I stopped after your answer "this one helped me..." and left it because that is that. A later correct answer may not be as useful as an earlier thought-inducing answer. I suggest shifting it back, or at least upvoting GMB's answer. The fact that both GMB and Gordon handled the NULLs incorrectly demonstrates the need to be careful around them.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to return all rows, including the rows that have a price of '0.01', UNLESS the rows with a price of '0.01' have one of 3 hold codes in the body of the OnHold column.

You could phrase this as:

```
WHERE NOT (
    Price = 0.01
    AND (
        onhold LIKE '%Pricing Hold%' 
        OR onhold LIKE '%Program  Hold%'
        OR onhold LIKE '%Program Hold%'
    )
)
```

Alternatively, assuming no `NULL` values in `Price`:

```
WHERE 
    Price <> 0.01
    OR (
        onhold NOT LIKE '%Pricing Hold%' 
        AND onhold NOT LIKE '%Program  Hold%'
        AND onhold NOT LIKE '%Program Hold%'
    )
)
```

I removed the single quotes around `'0.01'`: `Price` looks like a numeric value, so it should be stored as such (if that's not the case, you can revert that).

Comment: I restructured in the likeness of your first example. That wasn't the silver bullet though. It ended up being something related to trying to process a NULL onhold value through the "NOT LIKE '%%'" logic. When I put restructured that to "not(case when onhold is null then 'No Hold' else onhold end like '%Pricing Hold%'" to make sure I was passing a non-null string into the evaluation, it ran as intended.

Comment: Hold it - this answer doesn't deal with NULLs properly (and neither does Gordon's) - whereas mine does - yet this is the answer? Your entire issue is how to deal with NULLs.

Comment: Sorry dude.I asked for help on a query, and you gave me how to make a temporary table. Your solution didnt help me, but GMB's suggested restructuring assisted me in troubleshooting and isolating the root cause, which I fixed without a temporary table. Sorry, GMB helped more.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic:

```
Where Price = '0.01' AND
      onhold NOT LIKE '%Pricing Hold%' AND
      onhold NOT LIKE '%Program  Hold%' AND
      onhold NOT LIKE '%Program Hold%'
```

I would suggest `Price = 0.01`.  If you are storing `price` as a string, you should fix the data model, so the value is stored as a number (probably `decimal`/`numeric`).